# Set all files in Google Cloud Storage Bucket to public by default

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to set the files that are uploaded to a bucket to public by default.

When editing the bucket permissions, I get the popup below which I don't understand and I can't find any documentation about it. How do I set availability to the public?

The 'entity' selectboxes have the options: domain, group, user, project

The settings currently don't seem to set the files to public, because when I try to access a file through the url obtained with `CloudStorageTools::getPublicUrl($fileName, false)` I get:

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
</Error>
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You;ll want to set an ACL for that:

`gsutil defacl set public-read gs://bucket`

Answer (score -1):

### [Making Data Public](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public?hl=es)

Active Google Cloud Shell

```
gsutil acl ch -u AllUsers:R gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME]
```

> If successful, the response looks like the following example:

```
Updated ACL on gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME]
```

In the command, in the path after choosing the bucket, the CamelCase writing style must be respected.

---

I recommend applying the command to each file separately to get the **short URL**. Because if we assign the permission to the directory it will be possible to access the files but through a long URL.

Short URL:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/[BUCKET_NAME]/[FILE_PATH]/[FILE]
```